# What is the best way to fill a 2D array?

Tags: delphi

I am trying to fill an array using data from a database (Access), but when I run this code:

```
with dmSUPREMEDATA do
begin
  iNumberofRecords := ADOComplete.RecordCount;
  ADOComplete.First;
  SetLength(ArrSummary, iNumberofRecords, 3);
  for i := 0 to iNumberofRecords do
  begin
    ArrSummary[i, 0] := ADOComplete['Names'];
    ArrSummary[i, 1] := ADOComplete['Surnames'];
    ArrSummary[i, 2] := ADOComplete['Average'];
    ADOComplete.Next;
  end;
end;
```

This is the error that pops up:

[image]

Is there a better way to fill the array?
This is coded with delphi

Comment: Simple error. Hint: If there are 3 records how many times does a loop of 0 to iNumberofRecords run?

Comment: so i'm guessing i should change the 0 to a 1?

Comment: No, Dynamic arrays are zero based. Might also want to turn range checks on so it produces a range check error instead of an access violation.

Answer (score 3):

Your loop is going out out bounds of the array.

The 1st dimension of the array has `iNumberofRecords` number of elements, so it has valid indexes `0..iNumberofRecords-1`.  The indexes that a `for` loop uses are *inclusive*, so you are looping through indexes `0..iNumberofRecords`, which means the final iteration of the loop is accessing an invalid index.

You need to subtract `-1` from the loop counter, eg:

```
for i := 0 to iNumberofRecords-1 do
```

or:

```
for i := 0 to Pred(iNumberofRecords) do
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try create two for loops. Like a detail and subdetail, being one for the first array and other for the second.

```pascal
var arr2d := array of array of string;

SetLength(arr2d, 5, 5);

for var i := 0 to Length(arr2d) - 1 do
begin
  for var j := 0 to Length(arr2d) - 1 do
    arr2d[i][j] := 'Text [' + i.ToString + '][' + j.toString + ']';
end
```